# How do I silently disable PHP sessions using php.ini?

Tags: php, session

I'd like to completely disable PHP sessions, but transparently to code.

That is, make it so that `session_start()` returns successfully, and `$_SESSION` exists, and works within a single request in the sense that a single request can read/write from that global, but then that data is thrown away at the end of the request, no session variable is passed or cookie'ed, PHP doesn't attempt to store it on disk or anywhere else, etc..

I read in one place that using the file session-handler with a gc_lifetime of 0 works, but elsewhere saying that doesn't work.  And I wonder whether there's a no-op "handler" or similar thing that's the best/correct way to do this.

I prefer a solution using only php.ini, but an in-PHP solution is acceptable if that's the only way?

Comment: Why wouldn't you just call session_destroy() at the end of your file?

Comment: Would hate to attempt to debug code running on a configuration like that where stuff has deliberately been sabotaged to not work properly.

Comment: I could maybe add post-fix code to destroy, yes, but my preference is a "real" fix in which there's nothing to "trap" at the end, no holes where a session could get created, and as efficient as possible.

Comment: You can make a set of empty session handling functions.  Or, if you can overwrite $_SESSION, just dont start a session and create your own $_SESSION array.

Answer (score 0):

how about using auto_append_file directive in your php.ini file:

http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-append-file

then adding the kill code session_destroy() \unset in the append file

Comment: My understanding is that when subsequent code calls `session_start()`, the session will be started again?   http://us3.php.net/session_destroy

Answer (score 0):

PHP allows you to plugin a [SessionHandler](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php) which is responsible for storing and loading the sessions. You can disable session retention by making all of the session handler functions NOPs. Users will still receive a session cookie (because PHP doesn't know any different), but that may be acceptable, depending on your use case.

Use `auto_prepend_file` to set up the session handling before any code is run that makes use of sessions.